# PHPSESSID from B domain to A domain using on Chrome and Firefox, not on Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

From A domain, I make ajax/json requests to B domain. A domain contains a jQuery + JS script, and B domain the PHP files.

There is a strange behaviour that I can not understand why. The script runs perfectly on Chrome + Firefox, and not in Safari and IE. They both have the same problem. The time that chrome + ff return a specific json, the other two dont.

I am need of a quick and dirty fix, luckily I discovered that if I am in A domain, and visit B and the back to A, everything works!
As I noticed, there is a creation of a php sessid in A from B.

Is there a way probably with an ajax call to set a php sessid into A with the domain of B ? Thank you!

Comment: no, there isn't. if you allow 'external' calls to site B to set a session id of their own choosing, you'll be opening yourself to session hijacking. e.g. nasty person: `hey site B, my session id is barack obama, give me the launch codes`, site B: "ok!"

Comment: @MarcB I see, but how do you explain that if i go to A, then to B, back to A, it works... I mean it drives me nuts. And I see in the Inspect Element that B set a phpsessid in the A domain... An iframe maybe will solve this? I tried it to be honest. And also, how does this work on Chrome+FF! Oh God..

Comment: you can't pass the session cookie between different sites. that's just basic cookie security. and you do NOT want to pass the session IDs around in the query string - that's a massive security vulnerability. what you need is a single-sign-on system for both sites.

Comment: @MarcB I agree with everything you say, but how can it works perfectly on chrome and ff!

Comment: no idea. check the debug consoles in safari/ie and look for errors.

Comment: @MarcB no erros at all. the only thing is that in the response of a specific function, chrome and ff returns a correct json. ie and safari return empty. but when I visit B, then, they return it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use mozilla persona or any oath system.
There are several libraries out there that can solve this.
I already used this library: 
https://github.com/authbucket/oauth2-symfony-bundle
but I can't actually share the code, because it is owned by my company, but the documentation helps a lot :)